# the error about adding slave to master

Tags: kubernetes

## building a master localy.

I am trying to use /kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.sh

master is done!

some detail imformation:

```
K8S_VERSION is set to: 1.2.4
ETCD_VERSION is set to: 2.2.1
FLANNEL_VERSION is set to: 0.5.5
FLANNEL_IFACE is set to: wlan0
FLANNEL_IPMASQ is set to: true
MASTER_IP is set to: 192.168.1.104
ARCH is set to: amd64
Detecting your OS distro ...
Starting bootstrap docker ...
Starting k8s ...
4fa730ca61727c165345885639cbef4d5a34b5d0fa3a361c13b0abc3ead0dd58
{ "Network": "10.1.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
vDOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --mtu=1450 --bip=10.1.48.1/24"
```

## next add a vagrant virtualbox slave to master.

trying to use /kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/worker.sh

it bring some issue:

```
K8S_VERSION is set to: 1.2.4
FLANNEL_VERSION is set to: 0.5.5
FLANNEL_IFACE is set to: wlan0
FLANNEL_IPMASQ is set to: true
MASTER_IP is set to: 192.168.1.104
ARCH is set to: amd64
Detecting your OS distro ...
Starting bootstrap docker ...
Starting k8s ...
Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker-bootstrap/aufs/mnt/8881a46cdd1fe51b7f0f86e8659bc8f9c905089b0d86a273e85d134
c637041c1/tmp/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
```

I have two vm,

one is on public_network:192.168.1.110

other is on private_network:192.168.50.2

all is the same error output.

ps: can I use the worker.sh in aws ec2?

question is a bit miscellaneous,
hoping a cattle help me to consolidation.

Comment: the error should be occured in the step   "run flannel"    (http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/worker/)

Comment: the master_ip 4001 is up, but why the flannel container can't start?

Answer (score 0):

I am lucky enough to pass the work node, but I don't know the exactly reason.

now I package the vagrant box in my google cloud disk, url is below----[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WzutmgDDrodkpLRGM2c0J1RXc/view?usp=sharing][1].

before you take a public or private network with it, you should download a pre-compiled kubernetes version, and copy it to the vagrant folder.

use `vagrant init kube-slave` to start.